# Missing IPA character in \section{ \textit{}}

Tags: xetex, libertine

The title of sections doesn't display specific IPA characters, e.g. ʁ, ɢ, ʔ, ʃ, when they are italicized in the `\section{\textit{}}` context. I use Keyman as my Unicode IPA keyboard layout and it works well for typing in linguistic characters in paragraphs, examples, etc. But that strange outcome comes out with titles. Surprisingly, though, titles are printed correctly in TOC and List of Figures including those unread IPA symbols. I've read other questions on similar issues but haven't found an option that works for my problem. As you see I use `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\usepackage{libertine}`; I am wondering if there is a problem with the last package. A MWE is bellow:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, one side]{book}
\usepackage {setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}% Enable KEYMAN functionality
\usepackage{libertine}
begin{document}
%\hypertarget{TitlePage}{}
\maketitle
%\bookmark[dest=TitlePage]{Title Page}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
 \tableofcontents
 \newpage
 \printglosses
 \newpage
 \listoftables
 \clearpage
 \listoffigures
 \listoftodos
 \clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Valence Alternations}
\section{Reciprocality and beyond: previous work and goals}
This section describes the range of uses of the suffix \textit{-taʔ}. A previous work on the Mocoví spoken in Southern Chaco  analyzed \textit{-taʔ} as a \textit{reciprocal} verb marker \citep[see][45]{Gualdieri1998}.  This work provides further data on the uses of \textit{-taʔ} focusing on its syntactic and semantic properties.   

\section{The functionality of \textit{-taʔ}}
\subsection{Transitive predicates}
The suffix \textit{-taʔ} can in fact be used to express reciprocal constructions and occurs as the rightmost suffix of the verb morphological structure, as shown in (\ref{reciprocal marking}).    
%%%Rememeber that I'm using the {tipa} package. I'm not sure if this is the most practical package. It gives me the font but I think there is another option for the same output,  look for it. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems it is a problem with the font. Libertinus (from TeXLive) does not display a symbol for bold italics.

Comment: Right! Is there any way to come around this issue? @JairoADelRio

Comment: ```\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}``` solved my problem.

Comment: That is not a MWE.  Please cut out all the extraneous stuff and make it obvious what is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my tests, using libertinus rather than libertine has no effect on what I take to be your issue.  But \usepackage[sb]{libertine} works.  Evidently there is a bug in the bold italic variant.  The libertinus developers should be able to fix it for their fonts.